# Lightning app in the Salesforce mobile app

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

In the Salesforce mobile app, I am unable to see my Lightning App. How can I see my Lightning App so that all the navigation items are the same (and in the same order) as my Lightning App which I use on Chrome on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of the apps is bit different on salesforce1 as compared to salesforce classic.

Basically on salesforce1 you can add tabs and that tab will have the visualforce page which will be salesforce1 enabled.

Through different tabs you can view your app and VF pages.

If you want to see an “app” in mobile you will need to add it into Navigation Menu. Go to Mobile Administration –> Mobile Navigation.

For salesforce1 there is concept of Flexipage introduced. The flexipage allows to view different list views in only one page.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps helped solving my problem:

Setup --> New Salesforce Mobile App QuickStart